# Embedded tomcat jndi definition

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, embedded-tomcat-7

I'm using spring with embedded tomcat. I don't want `application.properties` to be used anymore, since it should be published to a webserver running tomcat and there I'm now using a JNDI dataSource from a context.xml which works very well. Now I want to define that JNDI resource for embedded tomcat, but it does not work.

What I've tried:

**context.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<Context>

    <Resource name="jdbc/db" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
        username="root" password="root" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db"/>

</Context>
```

**Configuration.java**

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    final JndiDataSourceLookup lookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
    lookup.setResourceRef(true);
    return lookup.getDataSource("jdbc/db");
}

@Bean
public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatFactory() {
    return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
        @Override
        protected TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(Tomcat tomcat) {
            tomcat.enableNaming();
            return super.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(tomcat);
        }
    };
}
```

and I'm getting:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]:
Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'jdbc/db';
nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/db] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
```

Please help me, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
lookup.getDataSource("java:/comp/env/jdbc/db");
```

without java:comp, jndi can not be found."comp" is short for component and is bound to root context.

Comment: therefore `lookup.setResourceRef(true);`, but I also tried it with prefix and it doesn't work.